# in Redux RTK getting " non-serializable value was detected in an action" for a Date?

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

With Redux RTK I'm getting this error "non-serializable value was detected in an action", however I just have Date's here, and they are serializable right?  So wondering why this is?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Redux does not serialize objects for you

You are currently putting the class instance of the date so it's not serializable ([because it's the class instance](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions)) however you can serialize a Date in Javascript

> Are dates serializable?

You can call [`new Date().toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

Which will produce a `string` in the store

Comment: actually I'm not sure what you mean by "class instance of the date"?  When I try this a date seems to serialize ok:  const dateVar = new Date()
console.log("Raw Date:   ", dateVar)
console.log("Sringified: ", JSON.stringify(dateVar));

Comment: I do not think redux is calling JSON.stringify for you

Comment: This is why you have to do `toISOString()`, `JSON.stringify`, `toJSON` etc... to serialize your date

Comment: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/search?q=JSON.stringify